# Kendo UI Upload widget - saveField and saveUrl

Tags: html, kendo-ui, asyncfileupload

Using Kendo UI upload widget, how to get the uploaded files in the wcf service operation. Provided the saveUrl option with my wcf method, but not sure how to get the uploaded file details. Still not able to understand purpose of saveField option. Please suggest.

//// service declaration
    public interface ISampleWcf
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            void DoWork();

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void SaveAttachments(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files);
    }
```

////Service Implementation.

```
public class SampleWcf : ISampleWcf
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }

        public void SaveAttachments(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            //HttpPostedFile file;
            var current = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            if(current != null)
            {
                var f = current.Request["files"];
            }
        }
    }
```

//// Jquery script

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
                     async: {
                         saveUrl: "SampleWcf.svc/SaveAttachments",
                         saveField: "customSaveField",
                         autoUpload: true
                     },
                     success: onSuccess,
                     error: onError
                 });

                 function onSuccess(e) {
                     alert('s');
                 }

                 function onError(e) {
                     // Array with information about the uploaded files
                     var files = e.files;

                     if (e.operation == "upload") {
                         alert("Failed to upload " + files.length + " files");
                     }
                 }
```

/////Web.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="WebApplication1.SampleWcf">
        <endpoint address="" contract="WebApplication1.ISampleWcf" behaviorConfiguration="webSupport"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="webServiceBinding" name="jsonEndPoint">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webSupport">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webServiceBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="34" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>


      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

The value of the "Async saveField" is "customSaveField". Then it should match the name of the parameter of your SaveAttachments.

```
public void SaveAttachments(List<HttpPostedFileBase> customSaveField)
```